# Overload of research themed tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

There seems be an amount of rarely used tags: 'research', 'historical-research' and 'research-techniques' which mean approximately the same. There is also a tag titled 'sources' and one 'methodology'.

Should not some of them be deleted/referenced/merged into one another?

Comment: historical-research is not even slightly "rarely-used". It was used 11 times this year alone. However, its still a good discussion to have, since most of the uses seem to be for reasons that could lead it to being applied to any question whatsoever on this site. **If** we keep it, someone needs to write a tag wiki for it with guidelines on when its appropriate to use.

Comment: Seems to me like they should be made into synonyms with each other - these seem like the sort of tags that just won't have an obvious correct choice.

Comment: Historiography?